# I got odd answer to my PhD application from Waikato University, What should I do now?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, university, new-zealand

In November 2023, I submitted my PhD application to Waikato University in New Zealand. As part of the application process, it is required for each student to establish direct contact with a supervisor and obtain their agreement. I followed this procedure, and the professor subsequently sent me the following message:

"I have uploaded your doctoral enquiry – so you should be able to continue your application from here Afshin"

Yesterday, on March 13, 2024, I received a rejection message from the university stating that "I must reapply because I did not secure an agreement with a professor prior to submitting my PhD application". Yesterday, I sent emails to the dean of the department and the prospective supervisor to inform them about the issue, but I have not yet received a response, which is typically normal.

I do not know what to do?

Comment: Did you have any other comunications between you and the professor between Nov23 an Mar24?

Comment: "I do not know what to do?" Wait until you hear back from them.

Comment: No EarlGrey he only replied once, wishing me the best for the scholarship competition. After that, I simply prepared the necessary documents and applied for the PhD program. The scholarship is not under the control of the supervisor; the decision is solely made by the dean of the department. Consequently, I awaited the outcome of both my scholarship application and my PhD application, without any further communication between myself and the prospective supervisor.

Comment: I understand that this feels urgent but you need to wait more than 1 day (has it even been a full day?) to expect a reply.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you misunderstood the requirements and so didn't fulfill them. They wanted you, I think, to get agreement from a professor to take you on. You got a weird communication that you misinterpreted as acceptance but that wasn't. It just stated that they had seen your materials.

I'd guess that they expected you to do much more working with this or another professor to get agreement. That would be consistent with application processes in many places, though not the US generally.

Whether they can make some exception for you or not, I can't say. I'd guess not, unless you can get some professor to agree to advise you very quickly.  But, as the comments have said, you need to wait for an answer to your query to know how to respond or even whether a response is appropriate.

My best guess is that you are stuck for the moment and need to carefully follow their procedures. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Buffy.